# How to programmatically post extended ascii character to facebook post?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to post special characters to facebook feed, but the characters shown in the facebook post doesn't show as I intended.

```
$tmp = "αвнιjτυz";

//This code works as I intended, showing "αвнιjτυz" on facebook post
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('message' => $tmp));

//I expect the displayed text in facebook post will be 'вн' but it shows strange characters instead
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('message' => substr($tmp, 1, 2)));
```

Any ideas why this happens and how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is unicode that you're working in. If so `substr()` won't work with unicode characters as they're represented with multiple bytes, you will need to use the `mb_substr()` function instead.

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('message' => mb_substr($tmp, 1, 2)));
```

Comment: Also `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')`

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. Anyway, I have just found another solution that is specific to my application. Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but missing the follow-up to Martin's question (and solution to question).

You should set the Content-Type of both the html and php to UTF-8. So at the beginning of the php code:

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

And with the html:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`